# submit forum (post) delete my ajax get

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax for sending to the server that a checkbox is checked and now other inputs fields need to be required:

EDIT: ok i will change the question to be more clarified.
i have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button_ajax').click(function() {
    var request =  jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'http://orenmizrah.git/nir1.php',
            data: {'id1': $('#input_text').val()},
            async: true,
            success: function(){
        console.log("sent");

    }
        });

    });
```

and now i check that i got the info in $_GET['id1'] with php code and if $_GET['id1'] is set, echo something to the browser.
the problem is that $_GET['id1'] is set but there is no output to the browser.
what i should do?

Comment: Just FYI: "Calender" is spelled "Calendar"

Comment: I think there is a full page postback happening

Comment: @AnkushJain what do you mean by full page postback?

Comment: Can you put the HTML form to the question?

Comment: The url parameter ends with 
`calendar=yes',`
I think the , should be removed --> 
`calendar=yes'`

Also add a `;` add the end of the variable declaration request --> ´});´

Comment: @YANTHO for modern browsers that shouldn't matter, just for IE it does basically.

Comment: @L Ja did not known that :) but its still good programming

Comment: Really not clear what the exact problem is. Where is the form submit code? A better problem description would also help

Comment: the form submit code build in php, the problem is that when i press on submit the $_GET['calendar'] (that send in ajax with get method) is deleted and the inputs fields that need to be required aren't.

Comment: That is because they are 2 seperate calls.
What you need to do is set a session variable with the calendar value.
Then when you submit check the session variable. Posting the html form would help the question.

Comment: i change the question maybe it will be more clarified

Answer (score 0):

No output is shown in the browser because nothing is done to show it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#button_ajax').click(function() {
        var request =  jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: 'http://orenmizrah.git/nir1.php',
                data: {'id1': $('#input_text').val()},
                async: true,
                success: function(data){
            console.log(data); // outputs the returned data to the console

        }
 });
});
```